# Chrome on startup to continue where I left off and one more page

Tags: google-chrome, browser, html, startup

Whenever I open chrome, I want:

1. All my previous pages are there
2. Another page, with a custom URL, is there. (With the possibility of me setting it to be `chrome://newtab`.)

Is this possible?

Is there a way that on `open specific set of pages`, I can add previous pages?

I have tried looking. The closest thing I could find was [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/lX1qvGAq1vc;context-place=forum/chrome). This is not exactly what I wanted.

I would like a simple and easy way of doing this. (I don't mind extensions but I couldn't find any.)

I want this to be done without any input from me every time. So no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Open Chrome browser and try pressing Ctrl+Shift+T. It restores all your previously​ opened tabs.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make this clear in the question, but I want it all without Ctrl + Shift + T. I'll change it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to automate Chrome GUI, it's possible using pywinauto. My student wrote an example dragging file from explorer.exe to Google Disk opened in Chrome. There are some tricks used here.

[test_explorer_google_drive.py](https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/ui-automation-course/blob/master/02_google_drive_Murashov/test_explorer_google_drive.py)

- Chrome requires command line parameter `--force-renderer-accessibility` to enable MS UI Automation support in Chrome. So if you're starting Chrome it should work for you. If you're trying to connect to existing Chrome window this might be a problem.
- Need to use `backend='uia'` explicitly for `pywinauto.Application` object. See the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) for more details, core concept and other useful things.

The relevant part of the mentioned script:

```
from pywinauto import Application

chrome_dir = r'"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"'

# start Chrome
chrome = Application(backend='uia')
chrome.start(chrome_dir + ' --force-renderer-accessibility --incognito --start-maximized <URL>')

# wait while page is loading (up to 10 sec.)
chrome['<Tab caption>'].child_window(title_re='Reload.*', control_type='Button').wait('visible', timeout=10)
```

Comment: I am pretty terrible at this kind of stuff. What exactly is going on here... What do I need to change to open recently closed tabs and more URLs? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, how do I download pywinauto for python 3?

Comment: Just run `pip install pywinauto` in cmd.exe (or maybe `C:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe install pywinauto` for specific non-default Python version).

Comment: You're right, desktop GUI automation is really complicated, but interesting. And pywinauto tries to simplify many things here. Feel free to ask more detailed questions by tag `pywinauto`. I'd also recommend reading the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) first.

Comment: Pywinauto works for Python2 for me but not 3. Is there another rep for python 3?

Comment: [pywinauto/pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) supports both Pythons (2.7 and 3.3+ up to 3.6). If something isn't working, please submit an issue.

Answer (score 1):

the details of this may depend on your operating system but on windows I can access a "master_preferences" file in C: > Program Files >  Google > Chrome > application.

the contents of the file looks like:

```
{
    "homepage": "http://www.google.com/",
    "homepage_is_newtabpage": false,
    "distribution": {
        "suppress_first_run_bubble": false,
        "import_search_engine": false,
        "import_history": false,
        "do_not_launch_chrome": true,
        "make_chrome_default": false,
        "verbose_logging": false,
        "ping_delay": -60
    },
    "sync_promo": {
        "show_on_first_run_allowed": false
    },
    "session": {
        "restore_on_startup": 4,
        "startup_urls": ["http://www.google.com/"]
    },
    "first_run_tabs": ["http://www.google.com/", "http://welcome_page"]
}
```

You can see there are settings for restore_on_startup
and startup_urls under the "session" heading

try editing those settings so the look like this:

```
"restore_on_startup": 2,
"startup_urls": ["http://www.google.com/", "http://www.theurlyouwant.com"]
```

You may not be able to configure these settings on your work or school computer as it requires administrator privileges. And also if you're not familiar with JSON pay especial close attention to the syntax (commas, quotation marks etc) I've used in my examples.

Comment: Where is the documentation for these settings? I can't find it anywhere..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, it's certainly not as technical a response as everyone else, but I use the [OneTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall) Chrome extension to do some of the stuff you're talking about.

I have a handful of pages saved to it, and I click the Restore All button and they all load in. You can save groups of tabs, and lock those groups so they're not easily deleted on accident, and name groups of saved tabs as well. I think it's pretty helpful, but it might not be exactly what you need/are looking for. Hope it helps though!